# No csrf token, instead sessiontokens?

Tags: csrf, architecture, access-token

Will a random-generated-session-key be enough, so that I can end the usage of csrf token? The front end, will receive the token when logged in. It will be stored in «local storage» at the client’s device and check for every request to backend. It will last for a given time, and when you log off, you end the session.

All sessions will be saved in a database by the backend. The backend will search for these keys with data from the requests. It will return data to front end, if the key is valid.

Will this be safe? Or is there any weak points in this architecture?

Comment: The description is really too vague to give you a proper answer. Is the "session token" the same as the session ID? *How* will the token be stored on the client's device? *How* and by whom will it be checked? When preventing CSRF attacks, those details are important.

Comment: Thanks for providing additional information. A few aspects are still unclear: When you write "session token", do you mean the session ID? How is the token sent to the server? Typically, the server embeds the token in HTML forms, but then why do you store the token client-side? And maybe most importantly: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you just want to get rid of the separate anti-CSRF token (why?) and use the session ID instead, this could be done a lot easier by using the classical Synchronizer Token Pattern, except with the session ID instead of an extra token.

Comment: to prevent CSRF, any value sent in a custom header that is required to exist is enough.  (as long as requests are required to be same-domain) However, proper anti-csrf tokens generated uniquely on each request and tied to the session will also help mitigate CRIME/BREACH attacks.

Comment: My thought was to send it in the response, as a string. But the orignal problem, is the process of verification when using private browsers. Then my csrf setup does not work as in normal browsers, and I can’t find a solution to fix This. I am using csrf tokens today, and want to keep it if the problem is solved..

Comment: The two common approaches for CSRF protection (called Synchronizer Token Pattern and Double Submit Cookie) are performed entirely by the server. The client doesn't have to do anything besides normal form submission, so the browser is irrelevant. If you have a problem with specific browsers or browser modes, then you must be using a different kind of CSRF protection. Unfortunately, it's still not really clear what you're doing and what the problem is.It also sounds like this is more of a general software issue than a security question. Have you checked the OWASP cheat sheet on CSRF protection?

Comment: The [OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) explains the basic concepts of CSRF protection quite nicely. Maybe there's just a misunderstanding.

Comment: I will read it! I’m using Django as backend and react frontend. If I had used Django templates, I would be much easier… but after hours of research, I still can’t find a solution on how to integrate the csrf token with my frontend properly. Do you know something about that? The main goal is to make a login interface

Comment: I hope it is understandable, I’m still a noobie…

Comment: See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax  (Basically your backend sets a cookie in response to each request that is set httponly=false.  Your front-end reads it and adds it to the headers for each request.  Your backend then confirms the token.... usually against another cookie that is httponly and signed)

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is only a threat with credentials that are sent automatically, or in other cases where authorization is granted automatically (e.g. by IP address). Therefore, cookies are the usual case where CSRF is a problem, but also things like client TLS certificates, IPSec, Windows Domain (Kerberos) authentication, and HTTP Basic or Digest auth can all be vulnerable too (this is not necessarily an exhaustive list).

In your case, since the session token is stored in Local Storage, it is presumably *not* stored in a cookie as well. As such, requests need to explicitly add the token somewhere - usually as an `Authorization: Bearer` header value, but sometimes in a different header or even in the body - because the browser won't automatically add contents of Local Storage to requests the way it automatically adds cookies (or some other credentials like the ones above) to requests.

As such, **your app is inherently secure against CSRF** if your credentials are only ever sent explicitly, not automatically. An attacker can't add the session token to a forged request without knowing what it is, and if they know that, they can just hijack the session directly, rather than tricking your browser into doing anything.

Comment: While this is true (if the application indeed never sends the session ID in a cookie), this kind of implicit CSRF protection seem awfully fragile. As soon as the session mechanism is changed (e.g., by also accepting a session cookie), chances are the entire protection will break down without anybody noticing. I would strongly recommend *explicit* token-based CSRF protection which does not rely on any side effects of the current session implementation.